# How to get currently running processes names from multiprocessing module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I know that in multithreading, there is enumerate method which I can use to get names of all current running threads. But for multiprocessing, what is the equivalent in the non pool like process call:

```
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(name='P1',
                    target=self.get_data,
                    args=(url,))
```

Ex, if I create above process, and one more process as above with 'P2', then the required snippet should return P1 and P2

Comment: do you want to know the identity of the `Process` [s] that your code forked?

Comment: @balderman, like I created the process P1 above, Now if I create one more process, P2, I should get the names of these. But if that is not possible, you can suggest some ID or something, that also will be helpful.

Comment: Yes - `p1.pid` will get you the process id. It is a unique identifier across the OS

Comment: @balderman, I don't need p1.pid. I need the IDs of all the running processes. Something like threading.enumerate, to get all the threads created.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `multiprocessing.active_children()` which returns a list of `multiprocessing.Process` objects.

For example:

```
for p in multiprocessing.active_children():
    print(f"child {p.name} is PID {p.pid}")
```

If you didn't use the `name=` argument to `Process()` the default names are, e.g., `Process-1`, `Process-2`, etc.

Note that this has the same limitation of `threading.enumerate()` in that it only identifies processes that have been started with `.start()` but have not yet terminated.

Also note this bit from the Python documentation:

> Calling this has the side effect of “joining” any processes which have already finished

Comment: It may `join` an already finished process, but it's no big deal to `join` multiple times... the only thing this affects is subsequent calls to `active_children` (joined processes are no longer part of the set)